# Unify quantities in one item

Tags: php

I have two arrays which have items and quantities and they are asociated by the index of the arrays. Example:

```
Items=XL,M,XL,S
Quantities=5,2,4,7
```

What I want to achieve is to remove the repetitive items and sum their quantities:

```
Items=XL,M,S
Quantities=9,2,7
```

```
    $uniqueTallesTotalesC = array_unique($tallesTotalesC);
    for($i=0;$i<Count($uniqueTallesTotalesC);$i++){
        for($e=0;$e<Count($cantidadesTotalesC);$e++){
            if($uniqueTallesTotalesC[$i]==$tallesTotalesC[$e] && $e > $i){
                $cantidadesTotalesC[$i] = $cantidadesTotalesC[$i] + $cantidadesTotalesC[$e];
            } else{
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"Example:"_ - please don't show strings, show actual PHP code for those arrays. Right now, we can't even tell which of those is supposed to correspond to which array variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just blindly zip-merge them together with summation:

```php
$items      = explode(',', 'XL,M,XL,S');
$quantities = explode(',', '5,2,4,7');

if(count($items) !== count($quantities)){
    throw new RuntimeException('Count mismatch');
}

$final = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    if(!isset($final[$items[$i]])){
        $final[$items[$i]] = 0;
    }
    $final[$items[$i]] += $quantities[$i];
}

var_dump($final);
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["XL"]=>
  int(9)
  ["M"]=>
  int(2)
  ["S"]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/6A5ZC

There's probably an autovivification that I'm missing that could simplify this greater.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create another array variable to hold the new items' quantities:

```
// I imagine these are your existing variables from your sample code
$tallesTotalesC = array('XL','M','XL','S');
$cantidadesTotalesC = array(5,2,4,7);

$uniqueTallesTotalesC = array_unique($tallesTotalesC);
// This will reset the indexes of the unique items array
$uniqueTallesTotalesC = array_values($uniqueTallesTotalesC);

// init a new quantities array with zeros
$uniqueCantidadesTotales = array_fill(0, count($uniqueTallesTotalesC), 0);

if (count($uniqueTallesTotalesC) == count($tallesTotalesC)) {
    // all items are unique so no need to loop through and sum the quantities
    $uniqueCantidadesTotales = $cantidadesTotalesC;
} else {
    foreach($uniqueTallesTotalesC as $newIndex => $item) {
        // get all indexes of the item in the old array
        $oldIndexes = array_keys($tallesTotalesC, $item);
        // for each of the index, get the sum the old quantity to the new quantity
        foreach($oldIndexes as $oldIndex) {
            $uniqueCantidadesTotales[$newIndex] += $cantidadesTotalesC[$oldIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!